# Segmentation fault while using cout

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault

I have a very strange issue. I'm seeing a segmentation fault while using COUT to print an int. below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello"<<std::endl;
    std::cout << 999.8;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MinGW (GCC 9.2.0)

I'm able to see the number printed to the Clion debug console. However, I cannot see it in the Clion's terminal. 
[image: Clion terminal output]

[image: Clion debug console output]

Comment: you are not printing an int anywhere in this program though.

Comment: Please also provide the command you used to compile the code and produce an executable

Comment: @Waqar it's just not it but any number. Also is this is strange but I'm able to see the application print to console in clion but cannot see anything in other consoles. There is no exception that's raised in clion as well.

commad would be very simple plain g++ main.cpp